# Sequence of if-else if in C

Tags: c, turbo-c

I' using the following logic for testing whether the triangle is isosceles, equilateral, scalene or right angled.

```
if (side1 == side2 || side2 == side3 || side1 == side3)
    printf("Isosceles triangle.");
else if (side1 == side2 && side2 == side3 && side3 == side1)
    printf("equilateral triangle");
```

I get the output for sides 3 3 3 as isosceles but not equilateral but when I interchange the logic that is write the logic of equilateral first I get equilateral. I can't understand what's happening?

Comment: 'else' is executed only if 'if' is not executed. Just remove 'else'.

Comment: Note that your list is not mutually exclusive; a right angled triangle can be isosceles. And beware comparing floating point ==.

Comment: @Bathsheba can you elaborate about FP ==, please?

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't use `else` in this case.

Code:

```
if (condition)
     code
else if (condition2)
     code2
```

Checks if *condition* is true. If so it executes *code*.
Only if *condition* is false, *condition2* is checked and *code2* could be executed.

Answer (score 3):

Your code "checks" the second `if` only when the first `if` is false.
logically the second if can be true only if the first `if` is true...

I would change the code to:

```
if (side1 == side2 || side2 == side3 || side1 == side3)
{
    printf("Isosceles triangle.");
    if (side1 == side2 && side2 == side3 && side3 == side1)
        printf("equilateral triangle");
}
```

Comment: +1 for the nested `if` (instead of just remove the `else`). It implied a equilateral triangle must be a isosceles triangle.

Answer (score 2):

`else` is executed only if `if` is not executed. Just remove `else` and it will be able to print both statements in such case.

Answer (score 2):

Side1 = 3, side2 = 3, side = 3, which means that side1 == side2 is true. That's why your program print out "Iosceles". Beacuse first if is true, second won't be checked. It would be only if the first one was false.

Answer (score 1):

Just switch the order of the if statements. Since every equilateral triangle is isosceles, you never make it into the elseif. Make your code read like this:

```
if (side1 == side2 && side2 == side3 && side3 == side1)
    printf("Equilateral triangle");
else if (side1 == side2 || side2 == side3 || side1 == side3)
    printf("Isosceles triangle.");
```

Alternatively, you can nest the equilateral if block inside the isosceles if block if you want both results printed:

```
if (side1 == side2 || side2 == side3 || side1 == side3){
    if (side1 == side2 && side2 == side3 && side3 == side1){
        printf("Equilateral triangle");
    }
    printf("Isosceles triangle.");
}
```

Another optimization to consider is that your equilateral check only needs two check to equalities. ie:

```
(side1 == side2 && side2 == side3) => (side1 == side3)
```

So, the if statement can read like this:

```
if (side1 == side2 && side2 == side3)
```